# Xcode Version 10.0 (10A255) - does not show svn (subversion) connected with project in source control menu

Tags: svn, xcode10

I have updated the Xcode version 10.0. I could open my existing projects and build / run them.

But I could not see the project or files connected to our SVN (subversion) in XCode menu "Source Control".

Please help if anybody has found solution to this issue.

Note:- The same projects were properly connected to svn and showing update / commit in the earlier version of XCode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [Xcode 10 release notes](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode_release_notes/xcode_10_release_notes), Apple removed Subversion support in Xcode 10.

You have three options: go back to Xcode 9, convert your Subversion repository to git, or use another tool to manage your Subversion repository.

Comment: Converting to Xcode 9 is not really an option for iOS developers or MacOS developers using Swift or Cocoa.